Arbitrary Waveform Synthesis
I am working on research project to generate a waveform of arbitrary shape given few parameters like Amplitude, Frequency, (if its a pulse then) pulse duration etc.  Are there any signal processing techniques to generate arbitrary waveform having an arbitrary shape with the given initial parameters. I heard using spline basis can do the task. However I am not able to understand where to start with things and what to look for. Can it be modeled as an optimization problem? Please provide how can I accomplish the task and provide guidance.

"arbitrary waveform" already means "of any shape". And what you describe is neither "of any shape" nor "arbitrary", but seems to be a very constrained kind of signal. I'm not sure what you're really aiming for; what is the thing you need this for? This feels like you're trying to solve a more general problem than what you actually have. Please tell us what you need to achieve, instead of speculating on a way there, without specifying what you need.

The other thing that is difficult to understand here is that, given a few parameters, then there are only a few control points in your "arbitrary shape".  You can't have a waveform with 20 different "arbitrary" bumps when you have only 5 control parameters.

exactly what @robertbristow-johnson: when you buy an "arbitrary waveform generator", what you typically buy is a fast DAC, and some memory to feed samples into that. The arbitrary waveform gets generated by the user of the device, not the device it self. "Arbitrary" really just means "up to you to define". You cannot say "arbitrary waveform" and "less parameters than it has (critical) samples" at the same time.

Thank you for improving your question's title! It still is missing the more important part where you describe your synthesis needs.

Basic answer: yes, it can be posed as an optimization problem. You need to give more information on your parameters to help us give you guidance on how to set up the problem.
